# Backgroundworker not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public Main()
{
     backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
       //Do Work
}



private void Start()
{
       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  //This works perfectly





     //////////This isthe offending code////////////
        try
        {


            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + "FileName.ini";

            using (var stream = File.Create(path)) { }
            File.WriteAllText(path, "Text to write");
            file = txtFilePath.Text;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(
                "Error saving configuration file.");
        }


       //////////////////////////////////////////


       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  //If moved here it does not fire!

       //Program contines here...


}
```

Not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: that's fairly hard to believe.  Is the code reachable?

Comment: Yes its reachable. It passes right over it

Comment: I think "some lines of code" are the important part in this mystery.

Comment: There must be more to `// some lines of code` than we are led to believe.

Comment: There must be more to this... do we know what is inside the "some lines of code" part? or inside the do work?

Comment: @Steve How can I access that property? If the first line works then I guess it must be set to True

Comment: @Jesse "some lines" basically sets some private fields, reads a file, runs some for loops, acceses an online resource using WebClient. Thats basically it.

Comment: I wonder if the backgroundworker is still running by the time the second "start" command is called, but that _should_ throw an exception if that happens.

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't think kr13 is actually trying to call it twice, in his comment he says **if** moved here it doesn't fire.

Comment: I found the offending code. Why could that code be causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 things here.

1. Start method is not being invoked (but you say that you can debug it, so thats not really an issue?)
2. Background worker is, well, a backgroundworker thread, if the foreground thread ends even before it starts; it will end, even though abruptly.

EDIT 1:

Can you try the following?

```
private void Start()
{
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  //This works perfectly
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
   ...
   ...
   // rest of your code.
```

Comment: Start() is being invoked. When debugging I press F11 on the RunWorkerAsync() code and it just goes to the next line..

Comment: Thats expected; threads do not spawn immediately (atleast while debugging). if you go few more steps it should enter the DoWork method, unless the foreground thread has already ended.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line:

```
bool running = backgroundWorker1.IsBusy();
```

Right after `RunWorkerAsync()` being called. And check its value with debugger or print message.
This will indicates the state of the thread - I suspect it finished its works right away (?)

Comment: So I guess the thread is running. Add some line to your DoWork() method and attach a breakpoint to see if your code goes there.

Comment: I have a messagebox right at the start of DoWork(), but it doesn't run

Comment: I think I will try adding the offending code to the DoWork() method